# forEach with uninitialized array

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, iteration

An array with uninitialized values `e.g. new Array(100)` doesn't iterate with `forEach`. The length is correct. Creating an array with `[undefined,undefined,...]` iterates as expected but creating an array with `[,,,,,]` doesn't.

I'm wondering if someone can explain this to me.

```js
var array = new Array(100),
    msg;

_init();

console.log("Array length:",array.length);

// forEach is skipped
a = ["forEach:"];
(array).forEach(function(i){
  a.push(i);
});
console.log(a.join(','));


// forEach is also skipped
a = ["forEach array without undefined:"];
([,,,]).forEach(function(i){
  a.push(i);
});
console.log(a.join(','));

// forEach is displayed
a = ["forEach normal array:"];
([undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined]).forEach(function(v,i){
  a.push(v);
});
console.log(a.join(','));

// for is displayed
a = ["for:"]
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
  a.push(i);
}
console.log(a.join(','));

// array.join is displayed (even the ough the values are empty)
a = ["join:"]
a = a.concat(array)
console.log(a.join(','));

// log to target div (ignore this)
function _init(){
  console = {log:targetlog};
}
function targetlog(){
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments);
  $("#target").append("<div>" + args.join(" ") + "</div>")
}
```

```css
span {
  outline:1px solid gainsboro;
  margin:2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: Any reason for doing `(array).forEach(..` instead of `array.forEach(...` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm wondering if someone can explain this to me.

That is the spec.

`forEach` and its brethren ignore "holes" in sparse arrays. For more information, see [this blog post](http://www.2ality.com/2012/06/dense-arrays.html).

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Description):

> `forEach()` executes the provided callback once for each element **present** in the array

The [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.foreach) says the same thing.

Comment: Array.apply(null, Array(3)) is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to fill in the holes, `Array(3).fill()` will also work if you have `Array#fill` available.

Comment: Im using an older version of node. It doesn't seem to be there. :(

Comment: fwiw, I voted to reopen the question (in error) attempting to see the duplicate question. Didn't see the banner at the top because it was above the fold. I did search for the question but didn't find anything. Thanks for the answer anyway. The blog is great. It makes perfect sense considering deletion of elements.